# Rolling Join multiple columns independently to eliminate NAs

Tags: r, join, data.table

I am trying to do a rolling join in `data.table` that brings in multiple columns, but rolls over both entire missing rows, and individual `NA`s in particular columns, even when the row is present. By way of example, I have two tables, `A`, and `B`:

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(v1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                v2 = c(6,6,6,4,4,6,4,4,4,6,4,4,4), 
                t = c(10,20,30,60,60,10,40,50,60,20,40,50,60),
                key = c("v1", "v2", "t"))

B <- data.table(v1 = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                v2 = c(4,4,6,6,4,4,6,6,4,4,6,6), 
                t = c(10,70,20,70,10,70,20,70,10,70,20,70), 
                valA = c('a','a',NA,'a',NA,'a','b','a', 'b','b',NA,'b'), 
                valB = c(NA,'q','q','q','p','p',NA,'p',NA,'q',NA,'q'),
                key = c("v1", "v2", "t"))

B
##     v1 v2  t valA valB
##  1:  1  4 10    a   NA
##  2:  1  4 70    a    q
##  3:  1  6 20   NA    q
##  4:  1  6 70    a    q
##  5:  2  4 10   NA    p
##  6:  2  4 70    a    p
##  7:  2  6 20    b   NA
##  8:  2  6 70    a    p
##  9:  3  4 10    b   NA
## 10:  3  4 70    b    q
## 11:  3  6 20   NA   NA
## 12:  3  6 70    b    q
```

If I do a rolling join (in this case a backwards join), it rolls over all the points when a row cannot be found in `B`, but still includes points when the row exists but the data to be merged are `NA`:

```
B[A, , roll=-Inf]

##     v1 v2  t valA valB
##  1:  1  4 60    a    q
##  2:  1  4 60    a    q
##  3:  1  6 10   NA    q
##  4:  1  6 20   NA    q
##  5:  1  6 30    a    q
##  6:  2  4 40    a    p
##  7:  2  4 50    a    p
##  8:  2  4 60    a    p
##  9:  2  6 10    b   NA
## 10:  3  4 40    b    q
## 11:  3  4 50    b    q
## 12:  3  4 60    b    q
## 13:  3  6 20   NA   NA
```

I would like to rolling join in such a way that it rolls over these `NA`s as well. For a single column, I can subset `B` to remove the `NA`s, then roll with `A`:

```
C <- B[!is.na(valA), .(v1, v2, t, valA)][A, roll=-Inf]

C
##     v1 v2  t valA
##  1:  1  4 60    a
##  2:  1  4 60    a
##  3:  1  6 10    a
##  4:  1  6 20    a
##  5:  1  6 30    a
##  6:  2  4 40    a
##  7:  2  4 50    a
##  8:  2  4 60    a
##  9:  2  6 10    b
## 10:  3  4 40    b
## 11:  3  4 50    b
## 12:  3  4 60    b
## 13:  3  6 20    b
```

But for multiple columns, I have to do this sequentially, storing the value for each added column and then repeat.

```
B[!is.na(valB), .(v1, v2, t, valB)][C, roll=-Inf]

##     v1 v2  t valB valA
##  1:  1  4 60    q    a
##  2:  1  4 60    q    a
##  3:  1  6 10    q    a
##  4:  1  6 20    q    a
##  5:  1  6 30    q    a
##  6:  2  4 40    p    a
##  7:  2  4 50    p    a
##  8:  2  4 60    p    a
##  9:  2  6 10    p    b
## 10:  3  4 40    q    b
## 11:  3  4 50    q    b
## 12:  3  4 60    q    b
## 13:  3  6 20    q    b
```

The end result above is the desired output, but for multiple columns it quickly becomes unwieldy. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins are about matching up rows. If you want to match rows multiple ways, you'll need multiple joins.

I'd use a loop, but add columns to A (rather than creating new tables C, D, ... following each join):

```
k     = key(A)
bcols = setdiff(names(B), k)

for (col in bcols) A[, (col) :=
  B[!.(as(NA, typeof(B[[col]]))), on=col][.SD, roll=-Inf, ..col]
][]

A 

    v1 v2  t valA valB
 1:  1  4 60    a    q
 2:  1  4 60    a    q
 3:  1  6 10    a    q
 4:  1  6 20    a    q
 5:  1  6 30    a    q
 6:  2  4 40    a    p
 7:  2  4 50    a    p
 8:  2  4 60    a    p
 9:  2  6 10    b    p
10:  3  4 40    b    q
11:  3  4 50    b    q
12:  3  4 60    b    q
13:  3  6 20    b    q
```

`B[!.(NA_character_), on="valA"]` is an anti-join that drops rows with NAs in valA. The code above attempts to generalize this (since the NA needs to match the type of the column).

Comment: This works great! I didn't immediately go for a loop since I sometimes find that if you're using a loop in R with a data structure, you're often doing it wrong. But sometimes it's unavoidable I guess.

Comment: Just so I understand what's going on, you're subsetting `B` on `!is.na(col)`, and doing a self rolling join to roll that column's data, yes? Is the `..col` an implicit call to `on=`?

Comment: Yep, the anti-join does the same thing as !is.na. The next join is essentially `A[, v := B[A, v]]`, except we can use `.SD` instead of writing `A` a second time; so it is not really a self-join. The `..v` notation is used to select columns stored in a variable (not to use `on=`; the key is still determining the join here).

Comment: Ah, I understand. Interesting that `.SD` refers to `A` and not `B` while in the brackets of the second join. But I guess `.SD` isn't defined in `i`, so it goes out one set of brackets. And makes sense re: `..v`. I'm still trying to assimilate the new syntax for `with=FALSE` style behavior, and I just got a little thrown by which is the outer scope in that case (goes out to variable definitions, not out one set of DT brackets). Thanks!

Comment: Learned something new about the usage of `as`.

Comment: @Frank I've discovered an edge case problem. Sadly I'm having trouble building reproducible example code, but I thought I'd ask anyway in case you can think of something offhand. If one of the columns in `B` has no `NAs`, the vector created to assign back to `A` with `:=` has more rows than `A` does, and throws a warning. Any ideas?

Comment: @ConnorJ You can skip a column that has no NAs like `for (col ...) if (anyNA(B[[col]])) do_stuff`, not sure if that helps. Sorry if that's not relevant; glancing again at this question, I don't remember all of what was involved.